# TensorFlow Training

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

Assuming I have a very simple neural network, like multilayer perceptron. For each layer the activation function is sigmoid and the network are fully connected.

In TensorFlow this might be defined like this:

```py
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    # Training Tensor
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, n_fft])
    # Label Tensor
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, n_fft])

    # Declaring variable buffer for weights W and bias b
    # Layer structure [n_fft, n_fft, n_fft, n_fft]
    # Input -> Layer 1
    struct_w = [n_fft, n_fft]
    struct_b = [n_fft]
    W1 = weight_variable(struct_w, 'W1')
    b1 = bias_variable(struct_b, 'b1')
    h1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)

    # Layer1 -> Layer 2
    W2 = weight_variable(struct_w, 'W2')
    b2 = bias_variable(struct_b, 'b2')
    h2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h1, W2) + b2)

    # Layer2 -> output
    W3 = weight_variable(struct_w, 'W3')
    b3 = bias_variable(struct_b, 'b3')
    y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h2, W3) + b3)

    # Calculating difference between label and output using mean square error
    mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_))

    # Train the Model
    # Gradient Descent
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(mse)
```

The design target for this model is to map a `n_fft` points fft spectrogram to another `n_fft` target spectrogram. Let's assume both the training data and target data are of size `[3000, n_fft]`. They are stored in variables `spec_train` and `spec_target`.

Now here comes the question. For TensorFlow is there any difference between these two trainings?

Training 1:

```py
for i in xrange(200):
        train_step.run(feed_dict = {x: spec_train, y_: spec_target})
```

Training 2:

```py
for i in xrange(200):
        for j in xrange(3000):
            train = spec_train[j, :].reshape(1, n_fft)
            label = spec_target[j, :].reshape(1, n_fft)
            train_step.run(feed_dict = {x: train, y_: label})
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the first training version, you are training the entire batch of training data at once, which means that the first and the 3000th element of `spec_train` will be processed using the same model parameters in a single step. This is known as **(Batch) Gradient Descent**.

In the second training version, you are training a single example from the training data at once, which means that the 3000th element of `spec_train` will be processed using model parameters that have been updated 2999 times since the first element was most recently processed. This is known as **Stochastic Gradient Descent** (or it would be if the element was selected at random).

In general, TensorFlow is used with datasets that are too large to process in one batch, so mini-batch SGD (where a subset of the examples are processed in one step) is favored. Processing a single element at a time is theoretically desirable, but is inherently sequential and has high fixed costs because the matrix multiplications and other operations are not as computationally dense. Therefore, processing a small batch (e.g. 32 or 128) of examples at once is the usual approach, with multiple replicas training on different batches in parallel.

See this [Stats StackExchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49528/batch-gradient-descent-versus-stochastic-gradient-descent) for a more theoretical discussion of when you should use one approach versus the other.

Comment: This is what I got from your post. In version 1 the weights and biases will not be updated until the program feed the whole batch of data to the model. That means 3000 data points will produce one big weight adjustment. And for version 2 it is like I am using those 3000 data points to update the weights for 3000 times, 3000 small weight adjustments. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: That's correct, yes. And if you do 3000 separate updates, the later updates will use more up-to-date versions of the parameters, which will tend to improve convergence (per data point trained).

Comment: @mrry Could you explain why "Processing a single element at a time is theoretically desirable"? I had always assumed that bigger batch size is better.

Comment: By processing a single element at a time, you would update the weights more frequently, therefore, the later computation can utilize more "evolved" network weights, potentially leading to better convergence (better accuracy). However, single-element processing would have low occupancy for GPU computation, leading to poor computation throughput, therefore longer training time. In contrast, bigger batch, pro: fast training speed; con: worse convergence (poorer accuracy).

Comment: Hi, I am just wondering how the updates work in detail. If I run the training data in a batch are they all computed sequentially and then is the gradient computed and the updates are processed? Or is done in parallel that the data in the batch is processed simultaneously in multiple threads until the gradient can be computed (and (synchronously?) updated)?

If I update the model after each training data, I assume it is done synchronously?

Comment: Lets assume that the batch sizes are the same in version 1 and 2. In that case is there a difference from the point of efficiency or any other aspect in the two implementations?

Comment: @Robert I think you have made a mistake. By taking single element at a time when you try to update the parameters you can get more fluctuating decent. But your case is correct if the network process all the examples at one iteration and take the average loss like in the first case.

Comment: @robert I think sgd is better in practice since Single samples are really noisy, while minibatches tend to average a little of the noise out

Comment: @mrry is the best!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's a difference. I think the second way loss function can be bit messy. It's more like online training. For each data point in the whole batch you update all of your parameters. But in the first way it's called the batch gradient where you take one batch at a time and take the average loss then update the parameters.

Please refer this link 
**https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49528/batch-gradient-descent-versus-stochastic-gradient-descent**
First answer is really good in this link